# Identify sci-fi collection: (1) aliens sell fake artifacts (2) US-USSR rivalry, iguanas in space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to track down a collection of SF short stories I read while in school in the mid-1980s.  I remember that one dealt with the inhabitants of an alien world making fake artifacts to sell to humans, and another was about US-Soviet space rivalry -- specifically, the US and the USSR were each conducting PR about their respective space stations.  The Soviets had a PR piece featuring a bear mascot, while the US's one (judged, somehow, to be the better of the two) was, if memory serves, about... raising iguanas in space.

Comment: Single-author or multu-author anthology?

Comment: Hi Michael, was _The Calibrated Alligator and Other Science Fiction Stories_ indeed the collection you were looking for? If yes, then please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: That's the one, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**I'm trying to track down a collection of SF short stories I read while in school in the mid-1980s**
You are looking for [*The Calibrated Alligator and Other Science Fiction Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38065) by [Robert Silverberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Silverberg), published in 1969.

**I remember that one dealt with the inhabitants of an alien world making fake artifacts to sell to humans**
This is [“The Artifact Business”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62906), first published in 1957:

> In that fiction story impostors plant fake artefacts in archeological sites
> in order to dupe the real archeologists and to take money from them for bringing them to "exciting" discoveries.
> <sub>[source](http://alt.news.macedonia.narkive.com/2oeAOQql/greeks-falsify-the-ancient-history)</sub>

**another was about US-Soviet space rivalry -- specifically, the US and the USSR were each conducting PR about their respective space stations.**
That is the title story of the collection: [“The Calibrated Alligator”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62905), first published in 1960.

**The Soviets had a PR piece featuring a bear mascot**

> And then, as an unexpected fillip at the end, the Russians
> unveiled their bear.
>     “Here is the mascot of Outpost Kapitza,” the Russian
> commentator declared sonorously, and the cameras focussed on a
> rotund little bear about three feet high.
> <sub>*The Calibrated Alligator*</sub>

**while the US's one (judged, somehow, to be the better of the two) was, if memory serves, about... raising iguanas in space.**

> [T]hey are force-growing a pet alligator to prodigious size. The ostensible purpose is to feed a hungry world with quickly maturing iguanas, but the actual motivation is to allow one of the young scientists to keep a beloved, smuggled pet.
> <sub>[source](http://galacticjourney.org/jan-28-1960-but-how-do-you-really-feel-february-1960-astounding/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

["Beyond lies the Wub"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Lies_the_Wub) perhaps... I remember a story about a guy buying an alien god / antique in one of the Philip K Dick Anthologies in that particular series.

From Wikipedia's plot summary:

> Peterson, a crew member of a spaceship loading up with food animals on Mars, buys an enormous pig-like creature known as a "wub" from a native just before departure. Franco, his captain, is worried about the extra weight but seems more concerned about its taste, as his ship is short of food. However, after takeoff, the crew realizes that the wub is a very intelligent creature, capable of telepathy and maybe even mind control.

Comment: I've edited in more details to your answer, so that people can judge better whether it fits the question (which, IMO, sadly it doesn't). Generally we expect story-ID answers to provide at least this level of detail; you might like to read [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer) on how to answer a story-ID question well.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Maybe the poster was thinking of the PKD [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Lies_the_Wub_(collection)) with the same title? Hard to tell. Fortunately Ubik has found the stories and book the OP was looking for.

Comment: @user14111 And learned something from your excellent answering style, by the look of it!